# Is there anyway to put python futures into a fifo?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, worker, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to put together a parallel processing python script. It uses futures to perform a heavy duty processing task, while the main thread builds tasks to for them to execute, and places them into a `multiprocessing.Queue`. There's another process that deals with the results of futures(reading the results and compiling the final result). I join the futures in my reduce step, because I can afford to wait there. However, I'm getting an error about not being able to pickle an rthread object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 234, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Here's my code as it stands, I can't seem to come up with an idea that actually works out nicely. The order of the results matters, if I submit job A and B. I need A to come out first then B.

Ideas I've had are:

- Create a callback that adds the result on done. (No guarantee of order)
- A normal queue that I wait for all of them to be done then submit stuff to the worker queue. (more complicated)

There must be a simple solution I'm not seeing here.

```
# Does video encoding in the background
def worker():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('out.avi', fourcc, 10, (1000, 75))
    n = 0;
    while True:
        task = workqueue.get()
        print(task)
        img = cv2.imread(task)
        out.write(img)
        os.remove(task)
        workqueue.task_done()
    out.release()
    cv2.destoryAllWindows()

workqueue = JoinableQueue(maxsize=50)
with open('runtime_trace.csv') as f:
    t = Process(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    max_size = get_max_alloc_size()
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, ['i', 'addr', 'size', 'alloc'])
    last_val = 0 
    vals = []

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
        for i,d in enumerate(reader):
            d = fix_types(d)
            if d['i'] != last_val:
                future = exe.submit(plot, vals, last_val, max_size)
                workqueue.put(future)
                vals = []
            vals.append(d)
            last_val = d['i']

        workqueue.join()
```

Comment: Can't you avoid the whole problem by putting a tuple `(plot, vals, last_val, max_size)` in the queue and creating `future` on the other side?

Comment: @Kashyap I'm trying to join the futures in order. I just posted the worker code. I don't really see a way to start up things in the worker without building a really stupid system over there. Unless I create a queue in the worker itself, and I don't want to have too many futures going at once. I want to limit the number of futures active to some number. Memory is a big concern for this.

Comment: I don't quite get the logic here. What you should be doing is 1. Put tasks (parameters needed to do a task) on a Q (not threads), 2. create a thread pool of workers, each dequeuing a task from queue, in a loop,  until Q is empty. Size of your pool is your limit. E.g. check out https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers You probably want "multiple evaluations asynchronously". Putting a thread in a Q seems counter intuitive.

Comment: @Kashyap I have an unknown number of things coming through, so I'm using the queue to launch the tasks, then get them pack when it's ready. I needed that bit to work in the background.

Comment: @Kashyap I figured it out based on what you said. I moved the executor into the background writer process, and created 2 for loops that walk over size of queue for as many elements that were created in that round.